Sci-fi book about man recruited to alt universe to work for secret employer, travels to alt universes, learns another version of himself was murdered
The book starts out with the man in his home universe, the last man alive. A group of people kidnap him to another universe; I think he sees the Moon is different and knows that what they're saying is true. They offer him the choice to stay here and work for their secret employer (about whom no questions can be asked) for a certain period of time and then be free, or he can be returned to his home universe and continue being alone.
He stays and begins traveling to other universes, collecting data and giving tours to rich people who want to see other universes about to end (like by getting hit by a meteor). He meets a woman who he finds out was dating an alternate version of himself before getting murdered. He begins digging into the murder and thinks the secret employer is behind the death.
On a mission to another universe where there are mindless worker-bee people, I think one of their co-workers gets killed and they find a tracker planted on the car that the employer put there that makes the normally docile people attack? The main character sneaks back to this universe to look for clues (I think they use coordinates to travel; you can only travel to universes that are close enough in range to your own).
I have tried googling this book so many different ways and can't get any results. I'm beginning to think this is just a very elaborate dream I imagined into reality.

In roughly which year did you read this?

This is Extinction Game (2014) by Gary Gibson.
It's the first book in the Apocalypse trilogy, and was followed by Survival Game (2016) and Doomsday Game (2019).
The Goodreads blurb notes that the protagonist, Jerry Beche, is rescued from a desolate Earth where he's the last man alive. He's then trained and sent on missions to gather weapons and data from other apocalyptic worlds with a team of specialists who were each recruited from a different alternate Earth. As the story progresses, he begins to distrust his new companions and the shadowy organisation they work for, known as 'the Authority.'

Jerry Beche should be dead. Instead, he's rescued from a desolate Earth where he was the last man alive. He's then trained for the toughest conditions imaginable and placed with a crack team of specialists. Every one of them is a survivor, as each withstood the violent ending of their own alternate Earth. And their new specialism? To retrieve weapons and data in missions to other apocalyptic worlds.
But what is 'the Authority', the shadowy organization that rescued Beche and his fellow survivors? How does it access other timelines? And why does it need these instruments of death?
As Jerry struggles to obey his new masters, he begins to distrust his new companions. A strange bunch, their motivations are less than clear, and accidents start plaguing their missions. Jerry suspects the Authority is feeding them lies, and team members are spying on him. As a dangerous situation spirals into catastrophe, is there anybody he can trust?

According to a review, the other people on Jerry's Earth were wiped out by a virus. The specialists he subsequently works with are known as the Pathfinders and are based on the Easter Island of an alternate Earth.

Jerry Beche is alone in the world. His only companion is the imagined voice of his lost wife Alice who, along with everyone else on Earth but Jerry, was claimed by a virus with an insatiable hunger. Jerry endures years of mindbending solitude, surviving from one day to the next, until one day he sees the impossible – human footprints in the snow. Someone is watching him.
For Jerry, the extraordinary happens. He is adopted by the Pathfinders, a group of survivors and explorers who are based on Easter Island, but not the Easter Island that can be found on Jerry’s Earth. This is a parallel Earth, one of countless, and the Pathfinders comprise the sole survivors from a whole range of Earths, each destroyed or devastated in umpteen different ways. Gathered together by the Authority, a mysterious body from one of the inexplicable rogue Earths, the Pathfinders’ mission is to explore these other worlds, familiar and yet so different, to recover certain artefacts, to discover the reasons for and why this chain of infinite ruined, empty Earths exists, each with its sole survivor.

According to another review, Jerry is initially captured and blindfolded by the Pathfinders on his Earth, before being taken away. When they remove the blindfold, he's surprised to see that a chunk has been taken out of the Moon.

Jerry Beche is possibly the last human alive on Earth; everyone else has succumbed to an artificial plague to which only he – it transpired – had immunity. Then one day he sees footprint in the snow around his wind generator. At first he thought that some of the conspirators behind the plague had survived and were after him. However the reality was even stranger, he was captured by strangers who blindfolded him. When he did get to see to where he had been taken, he was surprised to find that a chunk had been taken out of the Moon…
Jerry had been saved from a life of loneliness and recruited into a team that scours recently extinct, alternate Earths for technology. He could not have conceived of the various ways that 21st century human civilization could succumb, the variety of hugely differing apocalypses, but now he was becoming an expert. However he and the fellow members of his team – all similar survivors of civilization extinction events – did not know from where those running the operation originated or why they were so desperate for the technology. Worryingly, the technology the seemed to be particularly after seemed to be more weapons and military related. But there was an enticing deal. After a decade's worth of undertaking missions, the team members would be given a wealthy retirement on a pleasant parallel Earth similar to the ones from which they respectively came but minus its apocalypse. And so things would not have mattered had not the accidents started. And suddenly there was a real need to know who was controlling these missions and why…



Yes!! Thank you, that's it!
